# activerecord where not nil in has_one and has_many relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I have three models:

```
class Payment < ActiveRecord::Base
   ...
   has_one :order
end
```

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  has_many :items, class_name: "OrderItem"
end
```

```
class OrderItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
```

OrderItem has a column called `fulfilled_at` which is populated with a date when the payment is completed, otherwhise is null.

I need to make an activerecord query to obtain all the paid payments.

the result needs to be an `ActiveRecord_Relation` because I will use `will_paginate` on it, and I need to be able to `order` rows by date as well.

Here's what I tried:

getting the sorted list of payments with a query on `OrderItem` and then using `where( 'id in ?'` to get the payments, but then they were unsorted, and I tried to sort them with `decode` but apparently that doesn't exist in postgres

```
    filled_items = OrderItem.includes(:order).where.not(fulfilled_at: nil)
    filled_items = filled_items.order("fulfilled_at #{filter_params[:dir]}") if filter_params[:sort] == 'date'
    paid_payments = filled_items.map(&:order).compact.map(&:payment_id)
    
    logger.debug(" paid_payments: #{paid_payments}")
    @payments = Payment.includes(:user, order: [:items]).where( "id in (?)", paid_payments)
    if filter_params[:sort] == 'date'
      i = 0
      decoder = paid_payments.zip(Array.new(paid_payments.size){i+=1}).flatten
      @payments = @payments.order("decode (id, #{decoder.join(', ')})")
```

I tried doing all in a one liner:

```
Payment.includes(order: [:items]).where.not(order: {items: {fulfilled_at: nil}})
```

but the query generated here returns nothing, ending with: `WHERE ("order"."order_id" != '--- :fulfilled_at:')`

I need, later on in the code add `order` clauses, to order on various columns, including this date.

I'm not sure how to express this. any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If you need to get a list of paid payments, then the Payment model should have the information, e.g. a `paid_on` attribute. This is the attribute that should have its value set when the payment is made, not the `fulfilled_on` attribute of `OrderItem`. It's about keeping the information with the model to which it pertains.

Then the `Order` model would have (say) a `paid_on` attribute delegated to its associated payment.

```rb
# in order.rb
belongs_to :payment # I assume

delegate :paid_on, to: payment
```

And the `OrderItem` model would have a `fulfilled_on` method, defined like:

```rb
# in order_item.rb
belongs_to :order

def fulfilled_on
  order.paid_on
end
```

Then everything should be much simpler, because the information is in the right place.

Comment: Are you sure that model delegations are available in dB queries?

Comment: No, you can't use a model delegation in a query. I'm just saying that if you need to know the `OrderItem#fullfilled_on` date, then refer to the `paid_on` date for the associated payment iso storing `fullfilled_on` as an attribute on OrderItem. So the query to get paid payments doesn't query OrderItem, it queries the Payment model. Make sense?